# casting type using optional chaining in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

we can safety access to deeper level of object by doing

```
data?.user?.age
```

but can I do casting at the same line?

```
const ageInNumber = +data?.user?.age!
```

typescript doesn't throw error but I'm not sure it won't give me trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optional chaining operator (`?.`) returns `undefined` if its first operand is `null` or `undefined`.

Casting `undefined` to a number won't raise any exceptions, just silently returns `NaN`. If that's acceptable to you, then that part is OK.

However, the non-null assertion (`!`) is problematic. According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36031#issuecomment-586486687), TS evaluates `a?.b!` as `(a?.b)!`, asserting the entire chain, not just the `.b` part. So:

- **If none of the parts may ever be nullish**, then the **`?.`'s are superfluous**, and you should replace them with regular property access (`.`) to increase clarity.
- **If any of the parts can be nullish**, it will short-circuit with `undefined`, and **the non-null assertion is violated**. If that's the case, you should remove the assertion.

  However, if the last part (i.e. the `age` property of `data.user`) can be `null` (not `undefined`), then the entire chain returns `null`, which casts to `0`, therefore is indistinguishable from a real zero received in the data. To make it `NaN` too (or set a default value), you can use the nullish-coalescing operator (`??`):

  ```
   const ageInNumber = +(data?.user?.age ?? NaN)
  ```